# Open/show and close/hide popup by QML code

Tags: qt, qml

There is a `Q_PROPERTY` in my registered C++ class:

```cpp
// C++ Class
Q_PROPERTY(bool inProgress READ inProgress WRITE setInProgress NOTIFY inProgressChanged)
```

... based on which I intend to show a QML popup:

```
Popup {
    id: popup
    visible: cppClass.inProgress // Bind visibility to C++ Q_PROPERTY
}
```

But the pop doesn't show up. If change `visible` to `true` the popup is always shown of course.

#### Tried so far

Tried to use signal/slot connections to open/show the popup, but doesn't work:

```
Popup {
    id: popup
    visible: false

    Connections {
        target: cppClass
        onInProgressChanged: {
            if (cppClass.inProgress) {
                console.log("open ...")                   // This text is logged correctly
                popup.visible = Qt.binding(function(){return true}) // popup is NOT shown
                popup.open()                                        // popup is NOT opened
            } else {
                console.log("close ...")
                popup.visible = Qt.binding(function(){return false})
                popup.close()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Remove `visible: false`, it doesn't open the Popup, but it does keep it from appearing when opening

Comment: @Amfasis But I change visibility inside the signal-slot connections, so that should not be an issue. Right?

Comment: true, but worth a try to comment out all references to visible, I'd say. Also, does your popup actually have something in it? the example is empty, but that could be just the example (set a width & height to try)

Comment: Instead of using a binding like that, try a simple set value of `popup.visible = true`. Because your binding returns a constant, it's not adding any value to use one and I'm not sure if bindings are evaluated immediately on set or later in the event loop. If later, it could be interfering with the `.open()`.

Comment: I would check to make sure `inProgressChanged` actually fires.

Comment: @Amfasis Yes, the popup is filled with a progress bar

Comment: @JarMan It fires, double-checked by console logs.

Comment: Then a minimal reproducible example would probably help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code worked by triggering C++ signals further away from CPU-blocking operation:

```
Popup {
    visible: cppClass.inProgress
}
```

```cpp
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
cppClass->setInProgress(true);
QCoreApplication::processEvents();

// Dot not trigger signal immediately before heavy duty logic
//
// Do some less heavy statements 
// before CPU-blocking operation
// to make sure QML UI engine receives signals 
// and has time to show the GUI changes

// CPU-blocking operation
heavyDutyLogic.run();


QCoreApplication::processEvents();
cppClass->setInProgress(false);
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
```

Comment: You should not run CPU bound operations on the gui thread, you are blocking the eventloop